# C++ stream redirection

Tags: c++, embedded

In embedded C, i use printf which redirects to the system call "_write" which allows my to overload _write and redirect to Uart or Usb VCP.

Now in embedded C++ i would like to do the same for std streams std::cout std::cin.

Where do the calls lead to? where do i end up when calling cout/cin?? is there also a system call which i may overload?

```
printf("hi") --> _write()
std::cout << "hi" --> ????????????
```

Since i cannot debug standart library calls, i do not know what happens there.

if someone has experience with this, please give me some examples and tipps.

Comment: `iostream` internally uses `stdio.h`. The system call should be as same, i.e. `write(2)`. Use `strace` command if you want to see all system call.

Comment: I would search the compiler's documentation.  Most embedded system development chains have descriptions on how to overload the "hooks" for stream output.

Comment: That is not _redirection_.  Redirection in the context of stdio refers to sending stdout (in this case) stream to an alternative device or file.   What you are referring to is a low-level implementation dependency.

Comment: You can always create a stream that calls `write` and then change `cout.rdbuf` to that.

Comment: There is nothing like "embedded C" or "embedded C++". It depends on your (standard) libraries. But note that it is normally not advised to use the stream-IO functions/classes on typical embedded systems as they blow up the code uinnecessarily and can cause timing and memory (mostly stack) problems. Write/use simple conversion functions.

Answer (score 2):

Most standard C++ libraries are implemented using the underlying C library (which is itself a subset of the C++ library in any case).

It is not usual for the C++ library to require a separate retargetting layer to the C library.

You do not need access to the library source to demonstrate this.  You can simply place a break-point at `_write` (in your case - that symbol is by no means a given), and then run the `cout` code to demonstrate that it is implemented using the `_write` syscall.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to liliscent. strace of code above shows that both calls printf and cout end up in the same write system call.

```
...
brk(0x775000)                           = 0x775000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 17), ...}) = 0
write(1, "hihi", 4hihi)                     = 4
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```